# Using a custom_score to sort by a nested child's timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pretty new to elasticsearch and have been banging my head trying to get this sorting to work. The general idea is to search email message threads with nested messages and nested participants. The goal is to display search results at the thread level, sorting by the participant who is doing the search and either the last_received_at or last_sent_at column depending on which mailbox they are in.

My understanding is that you can't sort by a single child's value among many nested children. So in order to do this I saw a couple of suggestions for using a custom_score with a script, then sorting on the score. My plan is to dynamically change the sort column and then run a nested custom_score query that will return the date of one of the participants as the score. I've been noticing some issues with both the score format being strange (eg. always has 4 zeros at the end) and it may not be returning the date that I was expecting.

Below are simplified versions of the index and the query in question. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be very grateful. (FYI - I am using elasticsearch version 0.20.6.)

Index:

```
mappings: {
    message_thread: {
        properties: {
            id: {
                type: long
            }
            subject: {
                dynamic: true
                properties: {
                    id: {
                        type: long
                    }
                    name: {
                        type: string
                    }
                }
            }
            participants: {
                dynamic: true
                properties: {
                    id: {
                        type: long
                    }
                    name: {
                        type: string
                    }
                    last_sent_at: {
                        format: dateOptionalTime
                        type: date
                    }
                    last_received_at: {
                        format: dateOptionalTime
                        type: date
                    }
                }
            }
            messages: {
                dynamic: true
                properties: {
                    sender: {
                        dynamic: true
                        properties: {
                            id: {
                                type: long
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    id: {
                        type: long
                    }
                    body: {
                        type: string
                    }
                    created_at: {
                        format: dateOptionalTime
                        type: date
                    }
                    recipient: {
                        dynamic: true
                        properties: {
                            id: {
                                type: long
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            version: {
                type: long
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": { "participants.id": 3785 }
        },
        {
          "custom_score": {
            "query": {
              "filtered": {
                "query": { "match_all": {} },
                "filter": {
                  "term": { "participants.id": 3785 }
                }
              }
            },
            "params": { "sort_column": "participants.last_received_at" },
            "script": "doc[sort_column].value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": { "messages.recipient.id": 3785 }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [ "_score" ]
}
```

**Solution:**

Thanks to @imotov, here is the final result. The participants were not properly nested in the index (while the messages didn't need to be). In addition, include_in_root was used for the participants to simplify the query (participants are small records and not a real size issue, although @imotov also provided an example without it). He then restructured the JSON request to use a dis_max query.

```
curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/test-idx"
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test-idx" -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "message_thread": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "messages": {
          "properties": {
            "body": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "created_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'\''T'\''HH:mm:ss'\''Z'\''"
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "recipient": {
              "dynamic": "true",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            },
            "sender": {
              "dynamic": "true",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "messages_count": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "participants": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_root": true,
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "last_received_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'\''T'\''HH:mm:ss'\''Z'\''"
            },
            "last_sent_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'\''T'\''HH:mm:ss'\''Z'\''"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "subject": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test-idx/message_thread/1" -d '{
  "id" : 1,
  "subject" : {"name": "Test Thread"},
  "participants" : [
    {"id" : 87793, "name" : "John Smith", "last_received_at" : null, "last_sent_at" : "2010-10-27T17:26:58Z"},
    {"id" : 3785, "name" : "David Jones", "last_received_at" : "2010-10-27T17:26:58Z", "last_sent_at" : null}
  ],
  "messages" : [{
    "id" : 1,
    "body" : "This is a test.",
    "sender" : { "id" : 87793 },
    "recipient" : { "id" : 3785},
    "created_at" : "2010-10-27T17:26:58Z"
  }]
}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test-idx/message_thread/2" -d '{
  "id" : 2,
  "subject" : {"name": "Elastic"},
  "participants" : [
    {"id" : 57834, "name" : "Paul Johnson", "last_received_at" : "2010-11-25T17:26:58Z", "last_sent_at" : "2010-10-25T17:26:58Z"},
    {"id" : 3785, "name" : "David Jones", "last_received_at" : "2010-10-25T17:26:58Z", "last_sent_at" : "2010-11-25T17:26:58Z"}
  ],
  "messages" : [{
    "id" : 2,
    "body" : "More testing of elasticsearch.",
    "sender" : { "id" : 57834 },
    "recipient" : { "id" : 3785},
    "created_at" : "2010-10-25T17:26:58Z"
  },{
    "id" : 3,
    "body" : "Reply message.",
    "sender" : { "id" : 3785 },
    "recipient" : { "id" : 57834},
    "created_at" : "2010-11-25T17:26:58Z"
  }]
}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test-idx/_refresh
echo
# Using include in root
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/message_thread/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "participants",
          "score_mode": "max",
          "query": {
            "custom_score": {
              "query": {
                "filtered": {
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "participants.id": 3785
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "params": {
                "sort_column": "participants.last_received_at"
              },
              "script": "doc[sort_column].value"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": ["subject.name", "participants.name", "messages.body"],
            "operator": "and",
            "use_dis_max": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": ["_score"],
  "fields": []
}
'

# Not using include in root
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/message_thread/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "participants",
          "score_mode": "max",
          "query": {
            "custom_score": {
              "query": {
                "filtered": {
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "participants.id": 3785
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "params": {
                "sort_column": "participants.last_received_at"
              },
              "script": "doc[sort_column].value"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [{
              "match": {
                "subject.name":"test"
              }
            }, {
              "nested" : {
                "path": "participants",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "name":"test"
                  }
                }
              }
            }, {
              "match": {
                "messages.body":"test"
              }
            }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": ["_score"],
  "fields": []
}
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. You are asking about nested objects, but participants are not defined in your mapping as nested objects. The second possible issue is that score has type float, so it might not have enough precision to represent timestamp as is. If you can figure out how to fit this value into float, you can take a look at this example: [Elastic search - tagging strength (nested/child document boosting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095866/elastic-search-tagging-strength-nested-child-document-boosting). However, if you are developing a new system, it might be prudent to upgrade to 0.90.0.Beta1, which supports sorting on nested fields.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the mappings and the query above, as you correctly noted the missing nested objects. Still really stuck though, in case you have any other suggestions. I'll deal with the float issue once I get the query working.

Comment: I would try this https://gist.github.com/imotov/a75746f512dac1366d1d I couldn't test it since your mapping doesn't look like real JSON, so I cannot apply it to my index.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm back to trying to get this working. I gave your Gist a whirl and I don't seem to be able to get any results at all now. Here is exactly what I have along with the mapping in proper JSON...

Index:
https://gist.github.com/cedric/1c51e4cf4494ab5338a4

Query:
https://gist.github.com/cedric/0da99ca9faa646c48b35

Comment: Could you add some test data?

Comment: Your test data is malformed and doesn't match your mapping. After fixing these two issues everything seems to work: https://gist.github.com/imotov/24910861ec7a845707a2

Comment: Sorry about that. I got the query working following your example and am now just trying to add back in the other query and filter arguments. Here is a gist with the final query, which I'm having issues getting to work with the nested query custom_score: https://gist.github.com/cedric/87faaea0cadb5b6e4b42 Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: Hi @imotov. I think I've figured-out how to add everything except the multi_match query to the custom_score nested query. Any ideas on how to get this latest version of the query working? https://gist.github.com/cedric/fbf51753be2cbbbfc511

Comment: Your multi_match query tries to query fields from the root object (subject.name) and two different nested objects(participants.name and messages.body). It's not going to work. You need to convert multi_match into bool or dis_max query and move match queries for participants.name and messages.body into nested queries against corresponding nested objects. Alternatively, you can double index your nested objects on the root level by adding include_in_root setting to nested object mappings. This way your multi_match query will work as is, but you will significantly increase index size.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. I've updated the index to not nest messages and have added include_in_root to participants and use_dis_max to the query. Seems really close, but it's still not quite working. Here is the updated shell script with everything: https://gist.github.com/cedric/5a028ee9ba6e47129d23 -- thank you *sooo* much for helping me through this. Any idea on what I'm still doing wrong?