# Elasticsearch: search/order by overall tag weight

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to solve a problem that exeeds my very basic knowhow of elasticsearch.

I have a set of objects - each one has a set of tags. Like:

```
obj_1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
obj_2 = ["a", "b"]
obj_3 = ["c", "b"]
```

I want to search the objects using **weighted tags**. For example:

```
search_tags = {'a': 1.0, 'c': 1.5}
```

I want the search tags to be an OR query. That is - I don't want to exclude documents that don't have all of the queried tags. But I want them to be ordered by the one that has the most weight (sort of: each matched tag multiplied by its weight).

Using the example above the order of the ducuments returned would be:

- obj_1 (score: 1.0+1.5)
- obj_3 (score: 1.5)
- obj_2 (score: 1.0)

What would be the best approach to this regarding the document's structure and the correct way to query ES?

There is a similar question here: [Elastic search - tagging strength (nested/child document boosting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095866/elastic-search-tagging-strength-nested-child-document-boosting) only that I do not want to specify the weight when indexing - I want it done when searching.

My current setup is as follows.

The objects:

```
[
   "title":"1", "tags" : ["a", "b", "c"],
   "title":"2", "tags" : ["a", "b"],
   "title":"3", "tags" : ["c", "b"],
   "title":"4", "tags" : ["b"]
]
```

And my query:

```
{ 
    "query": {
        "custom_filters_score": {
            "query": { 
                "terms": {
                    "tags": ["a", "c"],
                    "minimum_match": 1
                }
            },
            "filters": [
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"a"}}, "boost":1.0},    
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"c"}}, "boost":1.5}    
            ],
            "score_mode": "total"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it only returns object 1 and 3. It should match object 2 (has tag "a") as well, or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE AS SUGGESTED**

Ok. Changed boost to script to calculate the minimum. Removed minimum match. My request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "custom_filters_score": {
            "query": {
                "terms": {
                    "tags": ["a", "c"]
                }
            },
            "filters": [
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"a"}}, "script":"1.0"},
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"c"}}, "script":"1.5"}
            ],
            "score_mode": "total"
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "3",
                "_index": "test",
                "_score": 0.23837921,
                "_source": {
                    "tags": [
                        "c",
                        "b"
                    ],
                    "title": "3"
                },
                "_type": "bit"
            },
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "_index": "test",
                "_score": 0.042195037,
                "_source": {
                    "tags": [
                        "a",
                        "b",
                        "c"
                    ],
                    "title": "1"
                },
                "_type": "bit"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 0.23837921,
        "total": 2
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 3
}
```

Still getting wrong order and one result missing. obj_1 should be before obj_3 (because it has both tags) and obj_2 is still missing completely. How can this be?

Comment: Looks like a pretty simple typo. Elasticsearch documentation of [terms query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query/) shows that `"minimum_match": 1` should actually be `"minimum_should_match" : 1`

Comment: Also using `boost` actually boosts the score given by elasticsearch for that query and not a absolute score. I guess with terms query it would be equivalent to what you want, but otherwise I would prefer using the `script` field to define the absolute score for each tag.

Comment: @rubish, I have tried using "minimum_should_match" before with the same result: only object 1 and 3 are returned..

Comment: Can you give me an example what I should put into the "script" field?

Comment: Can you just remove the `minimum_match` from the query, it should also work without that. For script field you can write something like: `"script": "1.5"`. As far as I understand, `"boost": 1.5` is equivalent to `"script" : "_score * 1.5"`

Comment: @rubish, just tried it but it still delivers wrong result. I have updated the question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems with my example.

1. The "a" term is a stopword so it was discarded and only "c" term was being used.
2. The custom_filters_score query has to include "constant_score" query so that all terms have the same weight before boosting.

Now it works!