# Elasticsearch : script_score using a nested value, tagging strength, nested document

Tags: elasticsearch

**Mission**
I am attempting to implement a function score query. 
[Similar to this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095866/elastic-search-tagging-strength-nested-child-document-boosting), only using the new `function_score`, rather than the old `custom_score`.

**Problem:**
I am failing to get a value from my script (always returns 0). This leads me to believe attempt to access the weight of the tag by `doc['weight'].value` is incorrect.

**I have three docs that look something like this (all from existing SO post):**

```
{
    "title": "3",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "B",
        "weight": 16
    }, {
        "tag": "D",
        "weight": 4
    }]
}
```

**My query:**

```
GET test-idx/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags",
          "query": {
            "terms": {
              "tag": [
                "C",
                "B"
              ],
              "minimum_match": 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
          { "script_score": { "script": "doc['weight'].value" } }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

**My Results:**

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test-idx",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
               "title": "1",
               "tags": [
                  {
                     "tag": "A",
                     "weight": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "tag": "B",
                     "weight": 2
                  },
                  {
                     "tag": "C",
                     "weight": 4
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test-idx",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
               "title": "2",
               "tags": [
                  {
                     "tag": "B",
                     "weight": 2
                  },
                  {
                     "tag": "C",
                     "weight": 3
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test-idx",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
               "title": "3",
               "tags": [
                  {
                     "tag": "B",
                     "weight": 16
                  },
                  {
                     "tag": "D",
                     "weight": 4
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it, will post answer once I SO will let me. Basically, bone headed bad query formation by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this was just a badly formed query. 
This works as expected. Duh!

```
GET test-idx/doc/_search
{
"query": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "tags",
    "score_mode": "avg", 
    "query": {
      "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "terms": {
              "tag": [
                "C",
                "A",
                "B"
              ],
              "minimum_match": 1
            }
        },
        "script_score": {
          "script": "_score * doc['weight'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: How does it know which item in the array to use the weight from? Are you sure this works as you intended?