# Can I use Azure Search to sort results based on tag weight

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to move my website from SQL server to Azure Search (or at least the core searching functionality).  I believe I understand how to get most of the functionality rebuilt but I'm stuck on one feature that is key to my site.

I would like to be able to sort the search results based on the weight on any of a fairly large number of tags.  By weight, I mean that I maintain a count of the number of users that have tagged a document with a particular tag.

It looks like you can do this in elasticsearch: ([Elastic search - tagging strength (nested/child document boosting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095866/elastic-search-tagging-strength-nested-child-document-boosting)).  But that uses features of elasticsearch that aren't exposed in Azure Search.

I don't see a way to use scoring profiles (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx) to do this either.

The only thing I can see that might work in a limited sense is to add a field for each tag that I want to sort on.  This might work for my particular case for now, but in the long run I'd like to make this work for user-defined tags.

Is this possible in the broad sense that is outlined in the elastic search case?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that for right now, the best way to do this would be to have a separate field that is periodically updated with the count of the # of users that have tagged a document.  Please note that you can be pretty efficient with this update by just posting this numeric value using [merge or mergeOrUpload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798930.aspx).  If you would like to see this feature added to Azure Search, it would be great if you could [cast your vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Comment: Thanks Liam.  I did vote for this.  And I have this working now.  It's nice that even though updating an index is fairly limited I am able to add a new tag without rebuilding the index.  But the "basic" price level's limit to 100 fields means this can't be a long term solution for me.